# how to power a raspberry pi zero w, with a 2x18650 bay, through GPIO

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, battery

I'd like to wire this bay to the GPIOs of a rpi zero w.

[image]

The bay welcomes 2S 2x18,650.
On each cell is written "9800mAh TR 18650 3.7v Li-ion".

My requirements are :

1. One micro-USB port must be able to transmit data to a smartphone, while not charging the phone
2. The other micro-USB port must serves as a charging port to recharge the 2S
3. The bay must provide robust (against loads) 5V to the pi, and up to 2A (those are values I found on the internet, correct me if I'm wrong)
4. The pi will power and exchange data with a USB-device that I hard-wired to the GPIOs as well

What should I buy in order to regulate and accomplish this please?

EDIT :
I found this

[image]

Will it work ?

Regards

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: You need a buck converter, 2 cells will produce between 6 and 8.5V and you need to convert it to 5V. Beware, 9800mAh for an 18650 sounds completely bogus, if you got them from a cheap no-name shop they are likely fake.

Comment: thank you, I edited with something i'm not sure whether it's a buck converter or not, and whether it will handle the 2*3.7v, could you confirm it please?